# How do I get 15V from a 34V power supply?

Tags: power-supply, audio, amplifier

I have an audio amplifier with a regulated power supply putting out around 34V DC. I would like to add a preamp which requires on 15V. How would I draw 15V from the main power supply?

Comment: You need a [tag:regulator].  Search through some of those questions first.

Comment: If the preamp only needs a little current something like a 7815 should work.  I think those generally go up to 35V in.  If the preamp draws close to 100mA or more, then a switcher will be easier than dealing with the heat from a linear regulator dropping 19V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as I'm guessing your preamp needs a reasonable amount of current then a step down switching regulator will be the best solution (if I'm wrong and it's <100mA or so then a standard e.g. 7815 as Olin mentions would do okay)

The reason a switcher is better in this scenario is the large input/output voltage difference. The linear regulator simply "burns off" the excess voltage whereas the switcher does not. To give an example, let's say your preamp uses 500mA:

With a 7815 you have:
(34V - 15V) * 0.5 = 9.5W dissipation.
This is a LOT of heat to get rid of, more than the load itself is drawing.

With a 90% efficient switcher, you get:
(7.5W / 0.9) - 7.5W = 0.83W. (the 7.5W comes from 15V * 0.5A, the 0.9 is the 90% efficiency)
This is clearly far more efficient.

Switching regulators are a little more complex and need a few more external components than a linear regulator, so depending on your experience/confidence level you can either build a circuit from scratch or purchase a ready built module.

If this is a one off and you are not looking to learn anything by building your own, then something like this [from eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-LM2596-DC-DC-Step-Down-Adjustable-Converter-Power-Module-/270920399233?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item3f141d3981#ht_2114wt_1139) is hard to beat:

[image: DC to DC switcher]

```
Specification:
Input voltage:4.5-40V
Output voltage:1.5-35V(Adjustable)
Output current:Rated current is 2A,maximum 3A(Additional heatsink is required)
Dimension(L x W x H): 43 x 20 x 12mm
Weight: 11.6g

Package Included:
1 x LM2596 adjustable power module
```

If you want to look at designing your own, then the datasheets and app notes of ICs like the above [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) are a good place to start reading.

Comment: The available stock of that specific one plummeted 50% after mentioning it. :) 5 left, very interesting plugin board for projects. Will buy two.