# +15V and -15V from a 24VDC Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage

Is it possible to get both a `+15V` and a `-15V` from a [24V power supply](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SWS600L-24/285-1742-ND/1766379)? This is for powering a controller [MKS 2179A](http://www.mksinst.com/docs/UR/2179-specifications.aspx).

[image]

Comment: What kind of research have you done so far? Here's a quick starting point: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/27383/49251

Comment: How much current does each of the outputs require?  Note that each of the outputs might require different amounts of current.

Comment: @DwayneReid From the specs I suppose each rail will use no more than 200 mA.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon I think the [LM2576T-15/NOPB](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM2576T-15%2FNOPB/LM2576T-15%2FNOPB-ND/363656) buck regulator can be used to get the +15V. If I get a +5V from a LM2576T-5, can the +5V be used as an input to 2 pieces of [MAX737CPD+-ND](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MAX737CPD%2B/MAX737CPD%2B-ND/1701709) to supply 200mA at -15V?

Answer (score 1):

We use a couple switchmode converters based on LTC chips to get +/-15V for the 640 version of this MKS thing. Lots of components.

If you're not making a circuit board you might want to buy a suitable DC-DC converter module with dual outputs. You could also use two 24V:15V isolated converters and wire the outputs appropriately.

By the way, although I think the data sheet says 200mA, I think in practice one supply uses a lot more current than the other (to operate the coil in the proportional valve). The current draw on that supply varies greatly as the valve opens up- the other supply is just for the op-amps in the signal conditioning and (analog) PID controller.

Comment: Seems like the [PYB15-Q24-D15-U](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PYB15-Q24-D15-U/102-3198-ND/4477456) may be used to supply +-15V from a +24V supply. Do board mounted solutions exist or do they get messy like you suggest with the LTC chips?

Comment: There's some nice solutions like the isolated CC6-2412DF-E (you tie the TRM pin to get +/-15 rather than +/-12). Read the applications data regarding extra filtering that might be required, but they're pretty straightforward and small.